# Quality of parametric 3D plot on 2D plane

Tags: plotting, graphics, stochastic-calculus

I need to plot the solution of an SDE which takes its values on the plane $\{z = 1\} \subseteq \mathbb R^3$. Here is the code of a minimal working example (the solution to the SDE is just the driving Brownian motion):

```
timeHoriz = 0.1;

trivialSDE = 
  ItoProcess[{{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {b1[t], 
     b2[t], b3[t], t}}, {{b1, b2, b3}, {0, 0, 0}}, {t, 0}];

bmPaths = 
  Table[RandomFunction[trivialSDE, {0., timeHoriz, 0.0001}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 60, Method -> "KloedenPlatenSchurz"], {i, 
    1}];

bmFun[t_] := 
  Table[bmPaths[[i]]["PathFunction"][t][[{1, 2, 3}]], {i, 1}];

boxDim = 2;

tanbmPlot = 
 ParametricPlot3D[{bmFun[t][[1]][[1]], bmFun[t][[1]][[2]], 
   bmFun[t][[1]][[3]] + a}, {t, 0, timeHoriz}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.001]}, Axes -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-boxDim, boxDim}, {-boxDim, boxDim}, {-boxDim, 
     boxDim}}]
```

Here `a` is a parameter that I would like to set to `1`. The problem is that if I set it to any nonzero value, the quality of the plot worsens considerably (as if it's interpolating on very few points). Set it to zero, and you get a high quality plot. The same thing happens if you code the behaviour into the SDE itself by modifying the initial condition:

```
trivialSDE = 
  ItoProcess[{{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {b1[t], 
     b2[t], b3[t], t}}, {{b1, b2, b3}, {0, 0, 1}}, {t, 0}];
```

Other workarounds fail too and I have absolutely no idea what's going on. How do I get a good quality plot of the solution regardless of the plane I want it to be valued in? Thank you very much for any help.

Edit: here are a couple of screenshots of what I'm seeing. The first is obtained by setting a = 0 and the second by setting a = 1 (or any other nonzero value).
[image: a = 0] [image: a = 1]

Comment: `numPaths` isn't defined, example doesn't run!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Sorry about that, it was set to 1 earlier in my code. I'll edit now.

Comment: Thanks! ...example still doesn't run

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Strange, it does for me.. have you set the parameter `a` to `0` or `1`?

Comment: upps... Now it works. I tried to improve the quality using the option `MaxRecursion->4` but no imrovement

Comment: Weird right? It refuses to plot properly unless it's on the plane z = 0... I don't know enough about the language, but can't imagine this not being a bug of some kind. Thanks for taking a look anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here I show, without understanding the background of the problem, the 3D plot:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{bmFun[t][[1]][[1]], bmFun[t][[1]][[2]],bmFun[t][[1]][[3]] + a}, {t, 0, timeHoriz}, {a, 0, 1.5},PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.001]}, Axes -> False, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, a}, Hue[a]],PlotRange -> {{{-boxDim, boxDim}, {-boxDim, boxDim}, {-boxDim,boxDim}}, All}[[-1]], MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

Equal colors show slices `a=constant`.

Especially the slices `a==0` and `a==1` are shown in the nect plot.

```
Show[
Table[
ParametricPlot3D[{bmFun[t][[1]][[1]], bmFun[t][[1]][[2]],bmFun[t][[1]][[3]] + a}, {t, 0, timeHoriz},ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, a}, Hue[a ]]]
, {a, 0, 1 ,1}] , Axes -> False,PlotRange -> {{{-boxDim, boxDim}, {-boxDim, boxDim}, {-boxDim,boxDim}}, All}[[-1]], MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it's the same!

Comment: I can't tell if there is a change at a = 0.. Have you not noticed a difference when plotting separately? Maybe it's a glitch on my version then.

Comment: The plot shows no significant difference for variing a I think!

Comment: I added a couple of screenshots of the plots I'm getting.